# How to store images do not use the resources

Tags: c#, image, resources, storage

I have a C # application and I need to keep in her pictures, but I can not use resources (resx). 
Is there then an alternative method?

update:
**ANSWER:**
My images is static, for this I will use Embedded Resource

[How create embedded resource](http://www.csharp411.com/embedded-image-resources/)

Comment: @ LarsTech, database - no, directory - now it use to be adverse effects if you delete a picture.

Comment: @svick, problems with porting to unix via mono

Comment: Please give us more requirements of your app. There are dozens of methods to do what you want just looking on current question. Why do not save just in folder(privacy concerns) ? Is it ok to have a database and save them like BLOB data (SQLIte for example)? Is it ok save them in folder and compress like secured zip file?...

Comment: DataBase - We do not want to use the database.

Comment: @simply, you don't want to? Why? Do you have reasons for that?

Comment: @Denis: so may be save them like secure ZIP files? At least this one, could be done I believe. Or one by one, or in some "logical groups", depends on your app. I'm not professional in Mono, but there should be some really good libs for ZIPing I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this a dynamic set of pictures or static? If static, you can compile the resource file as a separate assembly and then consume it. If dynamic, you need some type of data store to store the files. If file system does not work, a database is an option.

Comment: "compile the resource file as a separate assembly" - how do this? MonoDevelop can not do it automatically.

Comment: Make sure there is a resource manager in Mono:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.resources.resourcemanager.aspx. As long as it is there, you can use csc.exe to compile the files (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379563(v=vs.80).aspx). I would have to check if there are open source tools for .resx or if you have to start with Visual Studio or the Express SKU to set up the RESX to compile it. You did not have Mono in your OP.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned above, it really depends on whether or not they are static or dynamic. If static, you could use an Embedded Resource (instead of encoding them as constant byte arrays, as others have mentioned). If dynamic, you could store them in isolated storage.

Answer (score 0):

One idea comes to mind, but I probably wouldn't use it if at all possible: put the images into your code as arrays of bytes.

You could create `byte[]` fields for the images and initialize them in code. You could dynamically generate the code using either CodeDOM or Reflection.Emit.

Answer (score 0):

If images are not too large you can encode them into huge constant arrays in code.
This is not very elegant solution but what else if no file, no resource, no database?

Answer (score 0):

Given the options you gave us, that doesn't leave us with much to work with. Depending on the image size, you can use [this website](http://www.motobit.com/util/base64-decoder-encoder.asp) to encoding your images to Base64 and then store them in a `string`. Then you can use `System.Convert.FromBase64String` to convert them from base64 back to a byte array.

Another option would be to store your images on a web server and create a webservice on the server that you can consume to retreive the images.

These are not good methods though. The first idea is consuming a lot more memory then it would need to and the second method is just kind of ridiculous if you think about it. It is much much much better to use a database. You can use a database such as [MySQL](http://www.mysql.com/) that will work with both Windows and Mono. You can also use [SQLite database](http://www.sqlite.org/) so that the database is portable. There really isn't a good reason to store this in a database.

Answer (score 0):

I would go on my line: you can save on disk by using any **Mono ZIP** library that provides secure encryption.

**Zip**: cause you potentially will save a space

**Encryption**: if you need save some private data (family images, documents...)

Can group them based on your own app logic, or save them individually, with also some metafile attached, if you need also provide some information on image.

**Microsoft** uses this kind of "technology" for example for **DOCX** files. Try to change an extension of DOCX file to ZIP and unzip it into the folder. You will see the content.

Regards.